# What kind of data structure should I use for this data?

Tags: python, pandas, image

I've been using Pandas with the exhaust data from my job for about 2 years now, but I think I've somewhat outgrown strictly tabular data structures.

My problem: I work for a large logistics company (US domestic shipping), our system automatically produces a "sort report" at the end of every sort with useful operations data. Pandas worked great for compiling these reports and finding useful patterns (eg. high no-reads on camera tunnel 1). However, I want to get into image processing so I can better troubleshoot scan tunnel camera issues. I am able to gather scan tunnel image data from every package that is sorted (top, bottom, left, right of package). Along with the image data, there is tabular data such as the name of the shipper, destination, etc. The sort reports and image data are produced by completely different systems.

The end goal: I'd like to be able to organize this data so that the images are associated with their respective sort report and package data. I would like to eventually have an image processing pipeline, however I still don't know how I should go about even storing the data. I do almost all of my computation on an AWS Sagemaker instance. Of course I'm open to solutions outside of AWS.

In short: How do I store all this data while preserving the relations they have to each other?